# Getting just the top level text in an HTML Tag

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

First off, I am using Python and also Selenium and a bit of BeautifulSoup for webscraping. Maybe they can't work together, but this particular problem I've not been able to solve so far with either. I do not believe it is beyond the wit of man in any way, but it is beyond my efforts.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="summary">
            <div class="headingDate">09 January 2020 18:45 </div>
            <div class="callout"><span class="grey">Bob Smith</span>Student of the Week - JANUARY </div>


        </div>

        <div class="body">
            January 2020

                <div class="boxContent">                    


<div class="third-small">
    <div class="dropzone drop-smaller dz-clickable" id="d-3d3361e5-1e47-403c-a6b5-10137143f994">
        <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message="">
            <p class="centre"><i class="far fa-image biggest"></i></p>
            <p class="centre">Drag and drop file here to attach</p>
            <span class="bigLink"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Or choose file</span>
        </div>
```

The actual HTML goes on a bit more. Basically the 'body' tag is pretty large and contains this 'third-small' and other such items.

My problem is seemingly simple: I want to just get that 'January 2020' on its own from the body tag. But I've been unable to do it. If I use BeautifulSoup's 'gettext', it'll get me all the other text included (like 'Drag and drop file here to attach') with no obvious way to separate. Yes there are some newlines, but there are also those in the text above so I don't feel like that would be a safe way. I've also used 'find_all' from BeautifulSoup but that just gets me all contained tags, which doesn't include the text.

Is there a way? I've also tried using Selenium methods without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div class="summary">
            <div class="headingDate">09 January 2020 18:45 </div>
            <div class="callout"><span class="grey">Bob Smith</span>Student of the Week - JANUARY </div>


        </div>

        <div class="body">
            January 2020

                <div class="boxContent">                    


<div class="third-small">
    <div class="dropzone drop-smaller dz-clickable" id="d-3d3361e5-1e47-403c-a6b5-10137143f994">
        <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message="">
            <p class="centre"><i class="far fa-image biggest"></i></p>
            <p class="centre">Drag and drop file here to attach</p>
            <span class="bigLink"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Or choose file</span>
        </div>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("div", class_="body").contents[0].strip())
```

Output:

```
January 2020
```